# Quick Help With Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I match on the following string: A constant string name, followed by a period, followed by any positive integer, followed by another dot.

For example I want to find anything like this:

SomeText.1.
SomeText.99.
SomeText.100.
SomeText.1002.

Answer (score 4):

`Regex.Match(input, @"SomeText\.\d+\.");`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

`^SomeText\.\d+\.$`

To explain:

The `^` means the beginning of the line, as `$` means the end of the line. This ensure that the entire string matches the expression, not that something in it happens to match the pattern.

The SomeText part is self explanatory.

The `\.` means "match a single .". The \ is required to escape the meaning of the period, which by itself would mean "Any single character"

The `\d+` means "One or more digits".

Then the `\.` again, and finally `$` to signify that's where we expect the string to end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to retrieve the number, try:

```
var exp = new Regex(@"SomeText\.(?<number>\d+)\.",RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach(string s in allStrings)
{
    var collection = exp.Match(s);
    if (collection.Success)
    {
        int myNumber = int.parse(collection.Groups["number"].Value);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would look like `SomeText\.\d+\.`

Which, in c# code would be

```
var result = Regex.Match(stringToMatch, @"SomeText\.\d+\.");
```